# W8 and/or W9 for disregarded LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-8-ben

I incorporated an LLC as a nonresident non etbus sole owner and one of my clients is asking for a W9. When I offered a W8 instead, they declined and stated I need to provide them the W9. I’m looking for resources to tell them I should not send them one but the IRS is vague and some blogposts say this but doesn’t seem to convince them.

Should I provide them a W9 with the LLC EIN even if the LLC is a disregarded pass trough entity or should I insist the W8 is the only form I can provide?

AFAIK the W9 for pass trough LLCs should be filled with personal info and not the company name, EIN and address, meaning I will 1. Fill the form incorrectly or 2. Need an ITIN/SSN I don’t currently have.

Comment: An LLC can't be an employee (only people can be).  Can you clarify what you mean by "employer" in your question?

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right. Employer should read as “company contracting my services”.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but what does "non etbus" mean?

Comment: Etbus means engaged in trade or business in the US.

Answer (score 3):

The document that you might want to refer them to is [IRS Publication 515](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-515), Withholding of Tax on Nonresident Aliens and Foreign Entities.

In the section called “Documentation,” it has this to say about [Forms W-9 and W-8](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p515#en_US_2021_publink100019496):

> **Form W-9.** In most cases, you can treat the payee as a U.S. person if the payee gives you a Form W-9. The Form W-9 can be used only by a U.S. person and must contain the payee's TIN.

and

> **Forms W-8.** In most cases, a foreign payee of the income should give you a form in the Form W-8 series.

However, I’m not sure about your assertion that your U.S. LLC allows you to remain a non-U.S. person. [This article from Chron](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/american-citizen-own-llc-60049.html) about non-citizens owning LLCs seems to imply that you need to obtain a TIN from the IRS for your LLC.

Comment: I got a TIN for the LLC, an EIN. But given that I’m a sole owner of a disregarded entity, I should not use that EIN in the W9 but my personal SSN/TIN which I don’t have or need because I’m foreign. That’s the main reason to fill the W8 instead. Irt being a US person, I don’t match the criteria outlined here https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/classification-of-taxpayers-for-us-tax-purposes

Comment: Here’s the source about not using the LLC EIN in the W9: https://www.w9manager.com/how-should-an-llc-fill-out-a-w-9-form-correctly-ssn-vs-ein/

Comment: @mbalparda You could be right. I don’t know much about this.